# Random numbers with Maxwell distribution in C

Tags: c, random, distribution, numerical-methods

I need a 10,000 random number that is distributed with the Maxwell distribution.
For the normal distribution, I know that I have to use Box-Muller transform, but my question is why

```
 normal_distribution
```

Is defined as a variable (or anything I don't know) by default?
Is "normal_distribution" a function that gives numbers with normal distribution? If yes, is this possible for Maxwell distribution? If not, what should I do?
In fact, I want to learn how to create random numbers with Maxwell distribution in C.
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I have only seen that for C++. What header file is it in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your good bet is to use [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html). It is reasonable written and tested computational library in pure C. [Maxwell distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaxwellDistribution.html) is basically three normally distributed components squared and summed together.

Some untested code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

double sample_maxwell(gsl_rng* r, double sigma) {
    double vx = gsl_ran_gaussian_ziggurat(r, sigma);
    double vy = gsl_ran_gaussian_ziggurat(r, sigma);
    double vz = gsl_ran_gaussian_ziggurat(r, sigma);

    return sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz);
}

int main() {
    gsl_rng_env_setup();

    const gsl_rng_type* T = gsl_rng_default;
    gsl_rng*            r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);

    printf ("generator type: %s\n", gsl_rng_name (r));
    printf ("seed = %lu\n", gsl_rng_default_seed);
    printf ("first value = %lu\n", gsl_rng_get (r));        

    double Temperature = 300.0;   // K
    double kBoltzmann  = 8.62e−5; // eV/K
    double mass        = 1.0e+9;  // 1GeV/c^2, roughly atomic hydrogen

    double sigma = sqrt(kBoltzmann*Temperature/mass);

    for(int k = 0; k != 100; ++k) {
        double v = sample_maxwell(r, sigma);
        printf("%e", v);
    }

    gsl_rng_free(r);        

    return 0;
}
```

Maxwell distribution came from statistical physics, where molecule of gas has speed `v` and Boltzmann exponent comes to velocity distribution

f(v)d<sup>3</sup>v = C exp(- m v<sup>2</sup>/2 k<sub>B</sub>T) d<sup>3</sup>v

To get Maxwell distribution from this one, you could just express distribution in spherical over `v` coordinates, power term comes from Jacobian, basically. But one can easily see it is equivalent to product of three Gaussian distribution for each component. I'll refer you to the following page https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/Thermalhtml/node87.html and formula 7.217 in particular. Here is another link to friendly discussion https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19969/how-do-i-generate-maxwell-boltzmann-variates-using-a-uniform-distribution-random.

There are alternative ways to sample Maxwell:

1. Recognize, that sum of three squared Gaussian could be expressed as [Chi<sup>2</sup> distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with 3 degrees of freedom and sample v<sup>2</sup> via `gsl_ran_chisq(r, 3)`.
2. Sample v<sup>2</sup> as result of [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) via `gsl_ran_gamma_knuth(r, 3./2., 1.0)`.

And there is always Wikipedia where all of this is also stated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution

Comment: Hmmm; I'm not sure how you get the 'three values squared, summed, and square rooted' (where the square root part is not mentioned but is shown) from the discussion at Wolfram.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information.  I'm swimming out of my depth.  I think what you've suggested is probably good information.  I'm not sure of that.  Which leaves me in a dilemma — to up-vote, or not to up-vote.  You've put the effort in; of that I'm in no doubt.  I should've kept my head down.   Waaah!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, if it's a huckleberry over your persimmon, you ought to refrain from judgement, I would say.